# Single IP multiple servers

Tags: networking

I'm trying to decide how to use one IP address with the same ports to handle traffic for multiple servers. I want to use my single IP with multiple domains that are hosted on separate servers and I have not had to do that previously. I'm sure that I can direct domains to a different internal IP I'm just not sure what the best way will be.

Comment: Search this site for threads mentioning a "reverse proxy" or "ProxyPass".

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/678647/